# Emmet for .blade.php files in Intelli

Tags: php, laravel, intellij-idea

I currently work on a Laravel Project with Intellij-Ultimate.

How I can use Emmet in a `.blade.php` file. I can not find an option it; and no plugin.

Comment: `blade.php` is a PHP file. So search for `.php`

Comment: Its not just a php file. Its a blade.php file. @TalhaF.